# VBA parse HTML code to string with font formating PPT

Tags: html, vba, parsing, html-parsing, powerpoint

I have PowerPoint slide with TextFrame. TextFrame contains HTML-code. 
For example:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table width=950 >
            <tr><td>
                <font size = 2>[TEXT]<br>
                <b>[TEXT]</b>      
                 [TEXT]<br>
                </font>
            </td></tr>
         </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

I need convert text in TextFrame into [TEXT] with existing html font style (font size =2, bold etc.)

I tried code below, but it doesnt format fonts from HTML

```
Function HtmlToText(sHTML) As String
   Dim oDoc As HTMLDocument
   Set oDoc = New HTMLDocument
   oDoc.body.innerHTML = sHTML
   HtmlToText = oDoc.body.innerText
End Function
```